# trying to load data from api using json and ajax and it throws an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to load data from an api using ajax and json however it keeps giving this error.
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
  Global code

This is the html code used

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1">Old Content</div>
<button>Load</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    var url = 'http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~bookshop/v1.1/index.php/genre/list';
    $.get(url, function(data,status){
    console.log(data);
    });
});

});
```

Comment: Add this to your HTML: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`  The dollar sign (usually) refers to the library jQuery (You could also use Zepto.js this way, but that is less likely (which is a shame because Zepto.js is an excellent alternative to jQuery for modern browsers))

Answer (score 2):

The "$" keyword is used by the jQuery library, which you haven't included in your HTML to be loaded alongside the rest of the document.

Add this before your existing script tag to load jQuery from Google's CDN:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you might run into problems trying to retrieve cross domain json files. Consider looking up jsonp if that's the case.

Edit: fixed the URL

Comment: Iv add the code but this is the error that im getting now Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. (jquery.min.js, line 0)
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
 global code (test.js, line 1)

Comment: Whoops, copy paste error, edited in the correct URL.

Comment: Even with using that new url it is still throwing the same error

Comment: Maybe they are loading their html file by double clicking on it(if you use the protocol-less URL them you have to load the html from a web server (with HTTP or HTTPS))